# Kibana homepage shows blank after deleting all indices

Tags: elasticsearch, dashboard, kibana

I wanted to reset my elasticsearch indices and hence run the command

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'
```

Hence the `dashboard` index also got deleted and as a result I am getting an empty dashboard

[image: kibana-screenshot]
`Via` was the saved dashboard name. It was the default home too. How do I get kibana back to working state?

Comment: Dashboards are saved in the (hidden) .kibana index that was deleted when you deleted all indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the saved Dashboard is gone if you deleted all of the indexes. If you access the default Kibana page you can create it again and/or restore it assuming you have it backed up.

IE. `http://yourip/#/dashboard/file/default.json`